# Use a jooq condition with IN clause

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Let's say that I have 2 parameters, *firstname* and *lastname*; at least one of them is set.

What I want to do is to construct a *jooq* query to delete some records (from a table) with *firstname* and/or *lastname* stored in another table.
So basically I'd have three possibilities:

```
DELETE FROM table1
    WHERE table1.id IN
        (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE table2.firstname LIKE 'fname');

DELETE FROM table1
    WHERE table1.id IN
        (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE table2.lastname LIKE 'lname');

DELETE FROM table1
    WHERE table1.id IN
        (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE table2.firstname LIKE 'fname' AND table2.lastname LIKE 'lname');
```

Any idea how I could use *jooq condition* for this?
I could always execute 2 queries (one for selecting IDs from table2, the other for deletion), but I would like to do it in one step.

Thanks.

**LE**
I want to express these statements in Java code using jooq: first create a *jooq condition*, depending on which parameter is set, then use the condition in the *delete* statement

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Write:

```java
Condition condition = falseCondition();

if (firstnameIsSet)
    condition = condition.or(TABLE2.FIRSTNAME.like(firstname));

if (lastnameIsSet)
    condition = condition.or(TABLE2.LASTNAME.like(lastname));

DSL.using(configuration)
   .deleteFrom(TABLE1)
   .where(TABLE1.ID.in(
        select(TABLE2.ID)
       .from(TABLE2)
       .where(condition)
   ))
   .execute();
```